# Recover an older version of the file

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My laptop just shutdown unexpectedly when i am doing my project work on Visual Studio 2010. At that time I was editing a css file. After the system was restarted i see that css file was corrupted and it has nothing in it.

I was almost completed with my project. Now I am lost at vacuum and I don't know what to do.

**Is there anyway to get my whole code back ?**

The file is 7 KB in size and it shows a large amount of white spaces when opened in Notepad

Comment: If you didn't save, you might be stuck. Did you [check Visual Studio's AutoRecover location](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/02/14/did-you-know-where-visual-studio-saves-auto-recovered-files-in-the-case-of-an-unexpected-shutdown-151.aspx)?

Comment: By default VS has the auto save set to every 5 minutes, set it to the lowest time possible, this may help next time you have this issue. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/configure-autosave-autorecovery-of-crashed-projects-in-visual-studio-2005/